# How to fill out a card with information coming from DB using thymeleaf

Tags: html, database, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I´ve been checking other questions related to this but all of them are related to tables, I am retrieving a list of the records from the DB and I am trying to place the information that I have in cards, for example placing the name of the game, the price etc. The problem is whenever I try to place the information using thymeleaf the card disappear for some reason, in other words, I do not know how to set the specific details coming from the database into the HTML card.

This is my HTML where I am trying to replace the initially the name of the game and the price

```
<div class="introduction-container">
                                        <!--sección de titulo-->
                                        <div class="phrase-container">
                                            <p class="phare-style">Tu pasión por el <span class="gaming-style">gaming</span> tiene un nuevo hogar</p>
                                            <img src="images/controls.png" alt="controls"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--sección de videojuegos-->
                                        <div class="games-container">
                                            <div class="game-card" >

                                                <img src="images/marioBackground.jpg" alt="game"/>

                                                <p>Mario Bros</p>
                                                <p>$ 35</p>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Agregar al carrito" name="game" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="game-card">
                                                <img src="images/horizon.jpg" alt="game"/>
                                                <p>Horizon</p>
                                                <p>$ 35</p>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Agregar al carrito" name="game" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="game-card">
                                                <img src="images/starfield.jpg" alt="game"/>
                                                <p>Starfield</p>
                                                <p>$ 35</p>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Agregar al carrito" name="game" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="game-card">
                                                <img src="images/fifa22.jpg" alt="game"/>
                                                <p>FIFA 23</p>
                                                <p>$ 35</p>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Agregar al carrito" name="game" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="view-more"><a href="#">Ver más &rightarrow;</a></div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

This is the website, these are the cards that I am working on
[Screenshot of the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciYGW.jpg)

This is the controller

```
@Controller
@Slf4j

public class videojuegoController{
    
    @Autowired
    private videojuegoService videojuegoService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getGames(Model model){
        var listaJuegos = videojuegoService.getListaVideojuegos();
        model.addAttribute("videojuegos", listaJuegos);
        return "/index";
    }
    
}
```

This is the entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "videojuego")
public class videojuego implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_juego")
    private Long id_juego;
    private String nombre_juego;
    private double precio;
    private String desarrollador;
    private String fecha_lanzamiento;
    private String genero;
    private String descripcion_juego;
    private boolean lista_deseo;
    private String imagen_juego;

    public videojuego() {
    }

    public videojuego(String nombre_juego, double precio, String desarrollador, String fecha_lanzamiento, String genero, String descripcion_juego, boolean lista_deseo, String imagen_juego) {
        this.nombre_juego = nombre_juego;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.desarrollador = desarrollador;
        this.fecha_lanzamiento = fecha_lanzamiento;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.descripcion_juego = descripcion_juego;
        this.lista_deseo = lista_deseo;
        this.imagen_juego = imagen_juego;
    }
}
```

This is the database:
[Screenshot of the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTOMz.png)

I do appreciate any help/suggestion on this. Thanks

I tried adding the th:each={videojuego : ${videojuegos}}, then I tried to put into every field like this: th:text="videojuego.nombre_juego" or [[${videojuego.nombre_juego"}]] but still not working. Not sure about how to fill out data in a card like these.